# No obtengo los datos luego de hacer login en facebook con el plugin inappbrowser en ionic

Tags: ionic, facebook-api

1. Tengo una aplicación básica en `ionic 1` con 2 vistas home y
   dashboard
2. El plugin `inappbrowser` esta instalado y funcionando correctamente
3. Estoy usando el servicio de autentificación en la nube de [ionic.io/cloud](https://ionic.io/cloud)
4. Mi aplicación de facebook a la que hago login funciona correctamente.

El problema es que en la vista home esta el botón de hacer login a facebook, al darle tap esto llama al plugin y levanta la vista de autentificación del facebook sin problemas, coloco mi correo y password y al momento de ser success, solo se cierra y me lleva a la vista dashboard, que es donde deberían verse ahora todos los datos de la persona que se logeo.

El problema es ese, que *no muestra nada* en esta vista, supongo que me falta mucho código ya que solo hice el [tutorial oficial](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/facebook-auth.html)
y mi controlador de login puede que sea el culpable.

Por ahora, solo tengo estas lineas de código, son adaptadas de lo que entendí en el tutorial y realice pero no hay mucho mas.

```
.controller('auth', function($scope, $ionicAuth, $ionicUser,$state) {

 $scope.FacebookLogin = function(){

   $ionicAuth.login('facebook').then(

     //do something, but what!?
     // var full_name = $ionicUser.social.facebook.data.full_name;
     // var profile_picture = $ionicUser.social.facebook.data.profile_picture;
     // var facebook_raw_data = $ionicUser.social.facebook.data.raw_data;

   );   
 //  $state.go('dashboard'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este tutorial, funciona realmente bien:

[Ionic Facebook Plugin Integration](https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html)